# Laravel - How get images from /storage

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm having problems to get images from `storage`. So i upload files and images to `storage`. When the file is image i upload to `storage/images/` and the file goes there right.

In database it saves this: `/images/image01.png` .

In blade view i try to do this but doesn't work:

```
<img src="<?php echo asset("storage/". $images[0]->image)?>" />
```

In html it shows like this:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8000/storage/images/image01.png">
```

How can i do that?

Thank you

Comment: image not displayed in your view  ?

Comment: No. @SagarGautam

Comment: What's the problem ?

Comment: I can't show the image... @SagarGautam

Comment: There's no 'storage' folder in public of Laravel project

Comment: `asset` refers to `public/` directory so you should have file located at `public/storage/images/image01.png`

Comment: ok, I understand that! but if I put storaget_path() without asset it doesn't work yet. @SagarGautam

Answer (score 3):

Laravel provides some function to store file on storage path.

You should use that:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

You can see `storage/app/public/` will be created.

You shoud save all image in this folder.

Note: if you want to make new folder in `storage/app/public/` you should set 755 permission for this folder

Example: `mkdir('storage/app/public/avatar', 0755, true)`

Updated:Load in blade like that if you stored in `storage/app/public/avatar`

```
 <img src="{{asset("storage/avatar/img.jpg")}}" alt="">
```

Comment: @user3242861 in html you shoud use `{{ asset('storage/img.jpg) }}`. Do not specify app/public

Answer (score 0):

**Try to do as**

src="storage/images/image01.png"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<img src="{{ url('storage'.$images[0]->image)) }}" />
```