# asset() function return a path same as APP_URL

Tags: laravel, assets

when I try to get a path of any media using `asset('images/image1.jpg')` it returns path as

> 'http://localhost/project1/images/image1.jpg'

instead of

> 'http://localhost/project1/public/images/image1.jpg'

here is a code that I am using to get image

```
<img src="{{ asset("images/image1.jpg") }}" />
```

Comment: how do you use asset put your code that you use

Comment: Make a virtual host instead of accessing the project folder directly.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In laravel 5, the assets folder refer to the public folder, located in the root directory path.

In public folder, you can see index.php, this file executed very first, when someone open the application.

For removing the "public" folder path in URL, we should create a virtual host and assign the root directory path to public path.

I have xampp installed in my system.For creating a new Virtual Host, you need to open the vhosts file.

In my case it's located under the path.
**E:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf**

Copy the below code in your httpd-vhosts file

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerAdmin myadav2005@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs/[yourprojectname]/public"
    ServerName localhost.myproject
</VirtualHost>
```

You also need a entry in your windows hosts file.
this file can be found under the below path.

**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.myproject
```

Restart your Xampp.
Now your project can be accessed by "localhost.myproject" and you need not to add the public in your assets path.

Hope this all will help.

Comment: your solution is quite good. but I want to add /public in my assets path.

Comment: @SR_ Could you please explain why do you need that? 
If you need to change your default folders settings, you can simply go to "config/filesystems.php" and can update your folders settings according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

[asset()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-asset)

> Generate a URL for an asset using the current scheme of the request
>   (HTTP or HTTPS):

by default asset function doesn't return public as path

but you can add this path manually

```
<img src="{{ asset('public/images/image1.jpg) }}" />
```

Comment: someone( Sagar Gautam) commented to this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/44882645/7894379 that asset refers to public/ directory

Comment: if you mean this comment : ```asset refers to public/ directory so you should have file located at public/storage/images/image01.png``` they describe file location , not output path

Comment: whatever they describe. But the main thing is asset() refers to public/ directory